# Sqlite query syntax error - (Campare DateTime in Sqlite)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite query for search like this:

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Task.* FROM Task where Task.CreationDate >= '" + strStartDate + "'  ORDER BY Task._id ASC", null);
```

but I have this Error :

> SQLiteLog(4733): (1) near ">": syntax error

what is the problem? how I must write this query?
type of CreationDate is TEXT, and strStartDate is like '2012-04-05'

Comment: try with this http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/in.php

Comment: Post the complete exception message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this and solve my problem:

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Task.* FROM Task where 
        strftime('%s',Task.CreationDate) >= strftime('%s','" + strStartDate + "00:00:00 ')  ORDER BY Task._id ASC", null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what is the content of `Task.CreatioDate` and the variable `strStartDate`. 
Have values the same format like `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: type of CreationDate is TEXT, and strStartDate is like '2012-04-05'

Comment: the stored value in CreationDate is also like '2012-04-05'?

Comment: yes, they are in same format, actually they are DateTime but as String and TEXT.

Comment: I just try, and sqlite accept string comparison with '>='.
I tried on sqlite db with a TEXT field contains a dateField and it works.
Can you post the effective query send to the db?